# jquery file type selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, file-type

What is the correct jQuery syntax to only select certain file types?

e.g.

```
$("#fragment-1 a[SELECT ONLY ANCHOR TAGS WITH FILE TYPE OF MP3]").hide();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [attribute substring selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
#fragment-1 a[href$=".mp3"]
```

The `a[href$=".mp3"]` will select only those `a` elements whose `href` attribute value ends with `.mp3`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$("#fragment-1 a[href$=.mp3]").hide();
```

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors

Comment: Needs the quotes (single or double) around .mp3 in Gumbo's answer.